# Triangle pursuit (about a 2-dimensional recurrent sequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, fourier-analysis, recurrence-relations, normed-spaces

I define a recurrent sequence taking values in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ three initial (distincts) points . For example, I can let $x_1=(0,0)$, $x_2=(1,0)$, $x_3=(1,1)$.

Let: $N: x \mapsto \frac{x}{||x||}$ with $||.||$ the Euclidian norm.
For $n \geq 4$, I define:
$$x_{n} = x_{n-1} - N(x_{n-1} - x_{n-3}).$$

For the previous example: $x_4 = (1,1) - N((1,1))= \left( 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \right).$

The geometric construction of the first steps is illustrated in the following figures. At each step, it is like $x_{n-3}$ has been attracted by $x_{n-1}$ but kept at distance $1$.

[image: Construction of $x_4$]

[image: Construction of $x_5$]

[image: Construction of $x_6$]

After some iterations, we end with $3$ adherent points forming an equilateral triangle (following figure: initial triangle and final equilateral triangle):

[image: First and final triangles]

**Question.** I would like to have formula for the resulting equilateral triangles from initial triplets $(0, 1, e^{it})$ with $t \in (0, 2 \pi) \setminus \lbrace \pi \rbrace$.

**My attempts.** 
We separate the recurrence relation into 2 steps, for $n \geq 4$:

$$w_n := \frac{1}{\| x_{n-1} - x_{n-3} \|}, \text{ and}$$

$$x_n = (1- w_n) x_{n-1} + w_n x_{n-3}.$$

First terms are easy:

$$w_4 = 1,~~~x_4 = 0,~~~w_5 = 1,~~~x_5 = 1,~~~ $$

After that, it is more and more complex. The following formulas are true with $t \in (0, \pi)$ (additional care is needed outside this interval).

We let $a := \sin(\frac{t}{2})$, $a' := \cos(\frac{t}{2})$, 
$b := \cos(\frac{t+\pi}{4})$, $b' := \sin(\frac{t+\pi}{4})$,
$c := \sin(\frac{t+\pi}{8})$, and get:

$$w_6 = 1/(2a),~~~ \text{Re}(x_6) = 1 - a,~~~ \text{Im}(x_6) = a',$$

$$w_7 = 1/(2b),~~~ \text{Re}(x_7) = (2b - 1)b,~~~ \text{Im}(x_7) = (2b - 1)b',$$

$$w_8 = 1/(2c).$$

It is difficult to obtain next values. Functions with long periods are appearing, all shaped with absolute values everywhere. Maybe some Fourier wizard can help to get a closed form for $w_n$ and $x_n$.

**Graphically**

Here is the map when $t \in (0, \pi)$:

The initial triplet $(0, 1, e^{it})$

[image: Initial triplets]

And the mapping to adherent points:

[image: Mapping of those triplets]

Note that triplet corresponding to $t = \pi / 3 \approx 1.05$ is equilateral, so it remains unchanged by the mapping.

Comment: Identify the plane with complex plane and let $u_n = x_n - x_{n-1}$. Start from $n = 5$, $|u_n| = |u_{n-1}| = 1$. If one let $e^{i\theta_n} = \frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}}$, we have $\theta_{n+1} =  \pi - \frac12\theta_{n}$, one can use this to obtain an explicit expression of $\theta_n$ and hence expression of $u_n$ for $n \ge 5$ ( in terms of $u_4$ and $\theta_5$). In principle, we can sum $u_n$ to obtain series representations of $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{3k+\ell}$ for $\ell = 0,1,2$. However, those series don't seem to have any closed form expression.

Comment: Thank you for this comment, it helps me a lot. How do you show relationship between $\theta_{n+1}$ and $\theta_n$? I see which angle it represents, but don't get why it should have this form

Comment: when $|u_n| = |u_{n-1}| = 1$,  $\pi - \theta_{n+1}$ and $\pi - \theta_n$ are angles of an isoceles triangle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow indication provided by achille hui.

Let $u_n = x_{n} - x_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2$. $u_n$ represents the vector from $x_{n-1}$ to $x_n$. For $n \geq 4$, we have $\|u_n\| = 1$. So for $n \geq 5$, there exists $\theta_n$ such that $e^{i \theta_n} = u_n / u_{n-1}$. $\theta_n$ represents the angle between $u_{n-1}$ and $u_{n}$.

For $n \geq 5$, we observe that triangle $(x_{n-2}, x_{n-1}, x_n)$ is isocele with angles $\pi - \theta_n$, $\pi - \theta_{n+1}$ and $\pi - \theta_{n+1}$ (see figure for details). It follows $\pi = \pi - \theta_n +  2(\pi - \theta_{n+1})$ i.e. $\theta_{n+1} = \pi - (1/2) \theta_n.$

After some calculations, we get for $n \geq 5$ 
[this formula in only valid for $t \in (0, \pi)$]:

$$x_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-5} e^{\frac{2ik \pi}{3}} e^{\frac{i}{3}\left( t - \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \left[ 1 - \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right)^k \right]}.$$

[image: Angles in triangle]

*Angles in triangle $(x_{n-2}, x_{n-1}, x_n)$*